# How to output the value of the quotes in the input?

Tags: php, input, output

i have code

```
$name = 'Test world \"Example\" end';
<input type="text" name="text"  value="'.$name.'">
```

but in input on page in input i see `Test world \` only.

in furebug i see full code in input:

```
<input type="text" name="text"  value="Test world "Example" end">
```

In result i see that quote close earlier than necessary.

Tell me please how to make the right result(result should been with quote)?

Comment: htmlencode/htmlspecialchars

Comment: why you used \" not just " ? because you used single quota ' then escaping double quota not required

Comment: Or simply use `&quot;` which will output a quote for you.

Comment: and how delete `slash` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$name = 'Test world \"Example\" end';
echo '<input type="text" name="text"  value="'.htmlspecialchars($name,ENT_QUOTES).'">';
```

Answer (score -1):

`$name = 'Test world \\"Example\\" end';
<input type="text" name="text"  value="'.$name.'">`

Either that, or encode those slashes.